# Visual Studio cannot compile an Android Java file

Tags: java, android, visual-studio

Visual Studio 2019, Windows 10.

I can successfully compile a Native (C++) Android project and have it running on the phone with Visual Studio.

Now, in order to add some Java I first created a minimal Hello World project in Visual Studio for Android/Java.
However I get a note at the top:
*"Java Developer Kit installation not found (Status JDKRegKeyNotFound). Intellisense is not available"*
Also the code won't compile:

*"EXEC : [javac] error : Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later."*

**Installed: *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.4.1***

**JAVA_HOME set to *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.4.1***

**Path includes *%JAVA_HOME%\bin***

**Java SE Development Kit set to *C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.4.1* in *Options -> Cross Platform -> C++ -> Android* in Visual Studio**

[image: Android/Java]

I've googled for *Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.* but found only solutions for Android Studio or Eclipse.

Any suggestions how to fix these errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "Java Developer Kit installation not found ", it was a pending update which wasn't completed for some reason.

For "Source option 5 is no longer supported":
Edit (as an admin) C:\Microsoft\AndroidSDK\25\tools\ant\build.xml

Change line 71, 72 from

```
<property name="java.target" value="1.5" />
<property name="java.source" value="1.5" />
```

to

```
<property name="java.target" value="1.7" />
<property name="java.source" value="1.7" />
```

Now it compiles and runs as it should.
Note that I have not Xamarin installed as it is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to Visual Studio 2022 17.6.0 I got this warning. It seems the warning is produced from the Visual Studio Extension called ["Java Tools for Android Projects (Visual Studio 2022)"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualCPPTeam.JavaToolsForAndroidProjVS2022&ssr=false#overview), which is now deprecated.

I haven't investigated further but uninstalling this extension lets this warning disappear. To uninstall it go to Visual Studio -> Extensions -> Manage Extensions -> "Installed" section -> Look for "**[Deprecated] Java Tools for Android Projects (Visual Studio 2022)**" -> Uninstall